# Is it possible to write mp3 files from `tuneR::Wave` object in R?

Tags: r, audio, mp3, wav, tuner

mp3 to WAV is easy by `monitoR::readMP3` and `tuneR::writeWave`. What about Wave object to mp3?

I have done some audio splitting with R `tuneR::Wave` objects, and want to output them as mp3 files. I don't need the resolution as in WAV file which takes up a lot of unnecessary space.